# function won't display block

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting into JavaScript and I'm doing a little "IQ" test to practice. I'm using radio buttons and check buttons. The problem is when I select a radio button that has to call a function in an onclick event to display a DIV and when I select the other option in the same question it has to hide the DIV shown in the first selection.

Here is the function:

```
function show(x){
            if(x==1){
                document.getElementById("teams").style.display ="block";
                document.getElementById("activity").style.display ="none";

            }else{
                if(x==2){

                document.getElementById("teams").style.display ="none";
                document.getElementById("activity").style.display ="block";
            }

            }
        }
```

Here is where call the function:

```
<div>
&#191Do you like Futball&#63<br> 
<input type="radio" name="like" value="Ly" id="yes" onclick="show(1); "  checked>
Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="like" value="Ln" id="no" onclick="show(2); " >
No<br>
</div>
```

And I show this Divs depending which one is selected:

```
<div id="teams" style="display: none;">Here I display 5 checkboxes</div>
<div id="activity" style="display: none;">Here I display 5 Radio buttons</div>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: How are you loading your Javascript code? If it's on the same page, it should be inside a <script></script> tag.

Comment: it's inside <script> tags in the same page

Comment: So inspect the page using Chrome to see if there are any errors. If the Javascript hasn't loaded then it will log an error to the console when you click either one of the radio.

Comment: Wild guess. Declare var x; before function

Comment: What does or does not happen?

Comment: it says this: ReferenceError: show is not defined

Comment: i decalred var x=0; before function, but still.

Comment: @torazaburo it doesn't display a div when i select a radio button, it has to display a div when i select a radio button, but it does nothing

Comment: could you attach your whole html file?

Comment: omg, i feel so stupid, i got an extra bracket in other function, thanks for the help. Newbie mistakes :/

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this exact code and your javascript seems to be working.  If you have an error please post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            &#191Do you like Futball&#63<br> 
            <input type="radio" name="like" value="Ly" id="yes" onclick="show(1);"  checked>
            Yes<br>
            <input type="radio" name="like" value="Ln" id="no" onclick="show(2); " >
            No<br>
        </div>
        <div id="teams">
            teams
        </div>
        <div id="activity" style="display: none;">
            activity
        </div>
        <script>
        function show(x){
            if(x==1){
                document.getElementById("teams").style.display ="block";
                document.getElementById("activity").style.display ="none";
            }else{
                if(x==2){
                    document.getElementById("teams").style.display ="none";
                    document.getElementById("activity").style.display ="block";
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Works for me" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with your comment and what I assume is your down vote.  My post of a complete HTML document was different than the questioner's post.  It wasn't clear how he was structuring his code, specifically where he was placing the script.  I provided him a solution that showed that he was on the right track and that if he used this as a template, he should get to a working solution.  It turned out he had a typo and perhaps seeing it all put together so that he could compare it to his own code helped.  I think you're being a little overzealous with the down voting and moderating.

Comment: I don't understand how the script placement makes any difference, since the `show` function is not invoked until a button is pressed, which will be after everything is loaded anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I got an extra bracket in other function, that was the problem. It seems i was coding the function, got distracted and forgott to close it correctly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Instead of posting an "answer", delete your question.